# ASP.NET control events exception handling

Tags: asp.net, exception, controls, event-handling

Suppose I have a button in an aspx page that performs a save of the form data to the database. In the associated event handler, before sending the updates, I read something from a webservice, operation that might result in an exception. In case of an error I want to have an adequate message displayed on the page, and all the data in the form preserved. How can I achieve this? Also, all my pages inherit from a basepage, so I would like, if possible to have all the error handling code in the base class. I do not want, if possible, to surround any web service call with try-catch blocks, I would in case of any unhandled exception to call some method automatically, something like Page_error, but still preserve the data in my forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily put a method that manages the display message (maybe setting the text of some errorMessageLabel) in a superclass called from any derived class (if you wanna use inheritance to setup a template for your pages) if an exception is thrown (you can put the call to the superclas method in a catch block if there's actually an exception being thrown or you can manage this manually if the webservice is unavailable depending on your programming style).

As far as preserving the data presented, if viewstate is on and you are not populating your page dynamically then you're ok - if not, you need to explicitly save state information in viewState or session entries and retrieve them back if something goes wrong. 
This bit really depends on how your page is actually implemented.